# Can It be possible to use JPG images in splash screens instead of PNG images in Ionic 3 Project?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, png, jpeg, splash-screen

I have working project on Ionic 3 and I want to use JPG images as splash screen for all sizes. Can It be possible to use JPG images for splash screen in Ionic and I didn't find any document about this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Ionic implements the splash screen plugin from Cordova according to the [Ionic doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/splash-screen/). This plugin accepts png and jpg.
Here is the [doc from Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/#windows-specific-information).

You must specify the image file in you config.xml file (example for one screen size, on android):

```
<platform name="android">
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-hdpi.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
</platform>
```

And use it in the app:

```
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

constructor(private splashScreen: SplashScreen) { }
...
this.splashScreen.show();
...
this.splashScreen.hide();
```

Comment: I did the same. Everything working fine but when I build with production release. Then I am getting this error - (node:16551) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: /var/www/html/bhojpuri-app/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
platforms/android/res/drawable-land-ldpi/screen.png: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.

Comment: Your file is sreeen.png ? If yes, does it have a correct png format ?

Answer (score 0):

*This seems like a bit old question but still valid. So, for people that keep coming here.*

**NOTE: Using jpg splash screen will dramatically reduce the size of your bundle if your splash screen is a natural image, like a photo of a group of people, instead of a drawing.**

**This solution still works for Ionic 6**.

You can use jpg images with `cordova-plugin-splashscreen`. How to do this:

- Place your `splash.png` splash image into `resources` directory in your Ionic project.
- Run

  ```sh
  # Install cordova-res if necesary
  npm i -g cordova-res

  # Generate the resources in png format
  ionic cordova resources --splash
  ```

  This will generate **(in png format)** all the required splash assets for each platforms in directory `resources/<platform>/splash` and update your `config.xml` to reference the new assets.
- Now convert the splash assets with `imagemagick` and update `config.xml`:

  ```sh
  # Install imagemagick if necessary.
  sudo apt install -y imagemagick

  # Use mogrify to convert all splash screen assets to jpg
  mogrify -format jpg resources/*/splash/*.png

  # Remove all the previously generated `.png` assets
  rm resources/*/splash/*.png

  # Update the config.xml
  cat config.xml | sed -E 's/^(.*splash.*)\.png(.*)$/\1.jpg\2/' > config2.xml && mv config{2,}.xml
  ```
- Check the new bundle size and see how much it reduced.